# ld: library not found for -lcrypto on Big Sur

Tags: xcode, react-native

The project is based on react-native 0.63.2 and building a framework and it suddenly started to show the error. I have checked other post but didn't help.
Mac OS is Big Sure,
I am able to create an issue on Xcode 12.4 and 12.5

Other targets of the app, build without issue.
Framework build is failing for other branches on which framework was building successfully.

[image]